# create a new dataframe from selecting specific rows from existing dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in my pandas dataframe. df

```
id count price
1    2     100
2    7      25
3    3     720
4    7     221
5    8     212
6    2     200
```

i want to create a new dataframe(df2) from this, selecting rows where count is 2 and price is 100,and count is 7 and price is 221

my output should be df2 =

```
id count price
1    2     100
4    7     221
```

i am trying using `df[df['count'] == '2' & df['price'] == '100']`

but getting error

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: It's a classic: `df[(df['count'] == '2') & (df['price'] == '100')]`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You nedd add `()` because `&` has higher precedence than `==`:

```
df3 = df[(df['count'] == '2') & (df['price'] == '100')]
print (df3)
  id count price
0  1     2   100
```

If need check multiple values use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df4 = df[(df['count'].isin(['2','7'])) & (df['price'].isin(['100', '221']))]
print (df4)
  id count price
0  1     2   100
3  4     7   221
```

But if check numeric, use:

```
df3 = df[(df['count'] == 2) & (df['price'] == 100)]
print (df3)

df4 = df[(df['count'].isin([2,7])) & (df['price'].isin([100, 221]))]
print (df4)
```

Comment: but how do i join two results in 1 df.? i was thinking of creating two different dataframe for my two rows that i want and then append them?
is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Do you think assign to `df3` or `df4` ?