# Create a new dataframe by filtering characters from an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` dataframe:

```
id         name

63         T台
64        4S店
66    江南style
68        1号店
69         小S
70         大S
72          一
73         一一
74        一一二
77       一一列举
79       一一对应
80        一一记
81       一一道来
82         一丁
84        一丁点
```

I'm trying to create a new dataframe only with the rows that don't have characters from a certain list in the column `name`:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '%', '+']
```

I found several questions somewhat similar (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885318/create-a-new-dataframe-from-selecting-specific-rows-from-existing-dataframe-pyth)), but they are filtering based on specific values (e.g. `df[(df['count'] == '2') & (df['price'] == '100')]`), and not from a list of values.

The output should be a new dataframe without rows 63-70 in this example.

I tried to do something similar to get a list of `True`/`False` that I can use on the dataframe to filter:

```
('a' not in current_dataframe['name'])
```

But this only outputs one value for some reason:

```
>>> True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(l) for l in letters), flags=re.I)
print(df[~df["name"].str.contains(pat)])
```

Prints:

```
    id  name
3   68   1号店
6   72     一
7   73    一一
8   74   一一二
9   77  一一列举
10  79  一一对应
11  80   一一记
12  81  一一道来
13  82    一丁
14  84   一丁点
```

Answer (score 1):

With a list comprehension:

```
to_keep = [not any(letter in val for letter in letters) for val in df.name]
new_df = df[to_keep]
```

where `to_keep` is a boolean list and entries are `True` if not any letter in letters is in the corresponding value of `df.name`. Then we use boolean indexing to remain only those rows,

to get

```
>>> new_df

3   68   1号店
6   72     一
7   73    一一
8   74   一一二
9   77  一一列举
10  79  一一对应
11  80   一一记
12  81  一一道来
13  82    一丁
14  84   一丁点
```